# How to do server side authentication in php

Tags: php, authentication

[image: Server authentication]

How to do above authentication in PHP.I already have my own authentication in php but how to do above type login screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Apache, you can do this in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Basically, you have the username and password available in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`, which you can use to lookup users in a database or whatever.

A basic example, from php.net:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Does PHP_AUTH_USER exists for all kinds of servers? IIS, Apache, Nginx... etc?

Comment: According to [this page on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.server-indices) it will exist on any server with PHP installed and running.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following tutorial.

http://www.howtoforge.com/htaccess_authentication

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-authentication-in-htaccess.html

Answer (score -1):

That authentication is controlled by Apache, not PHP.

Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.seochat.com/c/a/Search-Engine-Optimization-Help/Apache-Basic-User-Authentication-htpasswd-Tutorial-for-SEO/